# Matlab defining matrix

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm new to matlab and the matlab's "get started" page on matrix doesn't seem to have instructions on how to define matrices such as this:

$A \in R^{n,n}$

$a_{i,j} = i^{j}, 1 \le i, j \le n$

how would I define non-static matrices like this on matlab? thank you

Comment: You can do this with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = [whatever number you want];
A = zeros(n);

for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        A(i,j) = i^j;
    end
end
```

The idea is to make a zero matrix of the correct size and then fill the entries with a nested `for` loop.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense